# Cleanup database state in a beforeEach?

Tags: cypress

In [Using after or afterEach hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks), it is recommended to clean up server/db state in `beforeEach` or `before`. I understand the rationale but I believe the text lacks some real use case. Here is a use case that I don't know how to solve following the best practice.

Imagine I'm testing my own clone of github. To have a clean environment for my tests, I want Cypress to use a clean temporary user and a clean temporary repository. To avoid conflicts between multiple Cypress instances targeting the same server (e.g., multiple front-end developers testing their changes in parallel), there should be one user and one repository dedicated to each Cypress instance. This can be implemented by generating users and repositories with well-known random ids (e.g., `temp-user-13432481` and `temp-repo-134234`). Cleaning up the mess in the database is just a removal of `temp-*` databases away.

The problem is *when* to clean up. If the clean up is done in a `beforeEach()` as is recommended, running a test in a Cypress instance will delete the data of other Cypress instances running in parallel.

Is there an obvious solution that I'm missing? How do people usually cleanup temporary testing data in a database?

Comment: I normally do not recommend these type of test mess with the DB. But I realize people do things differently. What I do is is mock all my API calls to return what I want, so I am never hitting the DB. It is my opinion that you test the DB with some other sort of test. I am not saying what you are doing is wrong. I just believe cypress is for testing the UX, not messing with the DB. So if I need a list of customers, I mock that and bring back fake data. If I save something I mock that also.I never touch the DB. I want to repeat I am not saying what you are doing is wrong or should not do it..

Comment: @Maccurt I see no chance to mock the whole API in a complexe project. You will have to maintain lots of fixtures and adjust them with every change in your API. Also when using the real API you get API tests for free in many scenarios.

Comment: We are cleaning our testdata in two steps. The first step is a suite scoped storage where some of the created testdata-ids are stored. After each `it` those ids are cleaned, depending on the type of testdata (some testdata can not be completly removed). Then in a second step, after each test run in jenkins, a subsequent jenkins job is stzarted to cleanup those data that was not cleaned (e.g. if cypress chrashes and so on)

Comment: It is a tricky thing to get right, and everyone has different needs. I do have some test that hit the real API and thus the DB, but they are all in my test environment. I try to mock anything where the data could change and thus break the outcome of the test. I would also like a script that sets the DB back to a baseline. I have a mixture of all. I personally want the API tested by the person who wrote the API, in my environment a a C# developer wrote the REST-API and we set up C# N-"Unit-test" (or integrated test) to hit the API. We were using postman, but....good luck.. nice conversation

Comment: @Maccurt how do you ensure your client works with latest API changes? You can test each separately all you want, but unless you have integration tests (e2e), you can't ensure correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be to not run tests in a distributed manner against a single remote server (and instead run the DB server locally on each client), but since this is not an answer to your question, here are a few ideas:

1. Set up a cron job that will clean up old test repos/users at the end of each day.

   If you only clean up users/repos that are older than e.g. several hours, it will avoid cleaning up resources that may still be used by running tests.

   You must ensure that the ids are random and large enough (i.e. have enough entropy) that you won't run into collisions even if you don't clean them up for a while.
2. Make each client (i.e. the PC running the tests) use a fingerprint that you'll use to namespace the repo/user in the DB, and clean them up before each test run.

   This way, each client will only clean up their own resources.

I'm leaning towards solution (1).

Comment: A fingerprint/namespace solution seems more generic for presented case, as it could be followed up with cleaning only data tagged with given fingerprint.